# Windows Phone SMS without confirmation

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any possibility to send SMS without using the launcher task: SmsComposeTask in Windows Phone 7.x ? There are apps like Emergency SMS that seem to do that, meaning the SMS can be send without confirmation from the user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to send an SMS without confirmation from the user. I haven't come across an emergency app that does this, but if they do, they may be using a web service to send the text instead of the phone's actual SMS facility. So instead of sending an SMS, they post the data to a web service which, in turn, sends the text message.

Comment: Just to add, in general you can't automatically invoke any system functions of WP7. Example: you can send the user to the WiFi page, but you can't turn it off for them.

Comment: Good addition. The philosophy of Windows Phone is to try and ensure that apps cannot do anything without the user knowing (e.g. sending texts to premium lines, making phone calls etc..). Whilst this can limit some legitimate apps, it also prohibits malware.

Comment: As far as I know - you can't even receive phone number to send it to specific web service without confirmation. So there is noway to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like with Windows 10 is now possible to do that
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/smssendandreceive/cs/smssendandreceive/sendtextmessage.xaml.cs

**Confirmed!**
With Windows 10 Mobile (10.0.12648.133, Build 10149) and Windows SDK 10158  I was able to send a sms without confirmation screens at all!

Add to your package manifest XMLs: 
  `xmlns:r="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"`

Capabilities:

`<r:Capability Name="cellularMessaging" />`

the full code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await SendSms();


        }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    }

    SmsDevice2 device;

    async Task SendSms()
    {

        try
        {
            device = SmsDevice2.GetDefault();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }


        SmsTextMessage2 msg = new SmsTextMessage2();

        msg.To = "+1000000000";
        msg.Body = "test";

        SmsSendMessageResult result = await device.SendMessageAndGetResultAsync(msg);

    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for that? I need it for a prototype (no need for Store review) and as far as I understand this all the win10m-solution ist the only one that works on a phone. The SmsDevice2-class is only working on Windows 8/8.1 (non-Phone).

Comment: This does not work on my Windows 10 Mobile (10512) device. But that is a proper Windows 10 Universal App that works on all devices Oo ``SmsDevice2.GetDefault();`` hangs

Comment: Okay, forget it. SOMEHOW I forgot to add the capability -.- It works. Awesome!