# Send sms Silently in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, sendmessage

I was trying to send sms to a group of contacts via SmsComposeTask  class.
But this class's Show() method only composes message in message app. I also want my code to send those texts automatically. Please help!!
Here is what i am using:

```
 SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();
 smsComposeTask.To = recipients; // recipients is the group of contacts
 smsComposeTask.Body =
 "Hello! This is a test sms message!";
 smsComposeTask.Show();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are allowed to do that? This could be a huge security risk as you could make it send sms messages to numbers that will charge money.

Comment: Refer my answers regarding Windows 10 in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695760/windows-phone-sms-without-confirmation/29247665#29247665

Answer (score 2):

See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/85dc6ef5-98a9-4a17-a5f0-171372d8d9a3/how-to-send-sms-from-a-windows-phone-page

> `using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;`
>
> `SmsComposeTask smsComposeTask = new SmsComposeTask();`
>
> `smsComposeTask.To = "2065550123"; smsComposeTask.Body = "Your SMS
>   text";`
>
> `smsComposeTask.Show();`
>
> After that a dialog will be show asking the
>   user whether to send the message.
>
> You cannot silently send an SMS

Also: https://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_send_an_SMS_in_Windows_Phone

> Note: In contrast to Symbian, Windows Phone does not allow you to send
>   sms "directly" or "silently" from your own app. As soon as sms sending
>   initiation code below is executed the native sms editor app will be
>   launched, giving the user the option to send the message or not.

I image this is done so that rouge apps can't send out a bunch of texts that will cost someone money.