# How to gain access to SMS in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, sms

I want to be able to send an sms at a specified time without being near my phone.
I have the following code:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage msg = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage();
msg.Body = message;
msg.Recipients.Add(number);
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessageManager.ShowComposeSmsMessageAsync(msg);
```

I get the following error:

```
The program '[5276] SendSMS.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'
```

what can I do to fix this and be able to access SMS?
Also, Is it possible not to show me the UI of the SMS but to actually send it? I need this pretty urgently.

Comment: On which line do you receive the access violation?

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/arunjeetsingh/SampleCode/blob/master/ComposeTestMessage/ComposeTextMessage/MainPage.xaml.cs
Do you get any `transports`?

Comment: Are you maybe calling the Show method from a background thread?

Comment: Using the same app not through debug it seems to work. Do you know how I might send without needing to press the button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone SMS without confirmation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695760/windows-phone-sms-without-confirmation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I windows phone 8.1 it is not possible to send SMS through your app in the backgournd with out user interaction